# What Latin translations exist of Dante's Divine Comedy?

Tags: resource-request, italian-to-latin-translation

Dante wrote the Divine Comedy in his native Italian rather than Latin, although there were [efforts to make Latin translations](https://biblonia.com/2018/08/31/giovanni-de-serravalles-latin-translation-of-the-divine-comedy/) over the ensuing centuries. I'm looking to find Latin translations which can still be found in print, and to also know the approach of the translator. Is it prose or poetry? If it's the latter, did they stray from the original much in order to have quality Latin hexameter?

Comment: FWIW, I found [printable edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=rt8_AQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=totius+libri+Dantis+Aldigherii&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGtdunndj2AhW28LsIHd1HB5EQ6wF6BAgFEAE#v=onepage&q=In%20medio%20itineris&f=false)  by the referred translator Giovanni de Serravalle. Note that it has *e* instead of *ae* at the end of words as many medieval text do.

Comment: Nice find! Swapping _e_ for _ae_ would definitely confuse me.